# Which knot to tie bulky objects together for transport

Tags: knots

I am looking for a knot that can be used to tie bulky objects together.

Usually I would use compression straps to tightly strap a tent to a bike handlebars, but I only have paracord at the moment.

I could use a [square knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/reef/index.php) but I am afraid it would come loose with all the vibrations.

It looks like some kind of [trucker's hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/truckersquick/index.php) would work, but I don't have a tension point I could use to keep it under tension?

What knots are good for this kind of situation?

Comment: [Timber hitch](https://www.animatedknots.com/timber/). Use [tautline hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch) to adjust tension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tie a loop in one end with a bowline, thread the rope though the loop and around the package, as you would with compression straps. If you can't get it tight enough with a couple of half hitches use a truckers hitch.

Answer (score 2):

A constrictor knot might be a good option. If you get it really tight, it might need to be cut off, but because of the way the outer wrap goes over two inner ones at one point, you can usually do this safely without risking cutting the item(s) it is tied around.

See:https://www.animatedknots.com/constrictorend/index.php